# List dependencies of package that I don't already have installed?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, apt-cache

I want to know ahead of time how many extra packages need to be installed for a
given package. I know I get something like this when I do an `apt install -s package | grep ^Inst`,  but can I get the same info using the `apt-cache`
command without needing to grep the output of the simulated `apt install`
command?

I know I can show a list of dependencies for a package with the command:

```
apt-cache depends package-name
```

and I know I can limit that list to only those dependencies that I have already
installed on my system with:

```
apt-cache depends -installed package-name
```

but how can I list only the dependencies that I *don't* yet have installed on
my system? Something akin to:

```
apt-cache depends -uninstalled package-name
```

Comment: The tricky thing here is that if a (direct) dependency *is* installed, then you know all of its sub-dependencies must also be installed. However if a (direct) dependency *isn't* installed, you don't know which other sub-dependencies may be required without recursively traversing all the way down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In layman's terms :)

You can find dependencies, recommends and suggests for a package like so:

```bsh
apt-cache depends package-name
```

You can limit it to dependencies only like so:

```bsh
apt-cache depends package-name | awk '/Depends:/ {print $2}'
```

You can check installation status of these dependencies like so:

```bsh
apt-cache depends package-name | awk '/Depends:/ {print $2}' | xargs apt list
```

You can print only uninstalled dependencies for a package like so:

```bsh
apt-cache depends package-name | awk '/Depends:/ {print $2}' | xargs apt list | awk '!/installed/ {print}'
```